# How to add objects into an array of reducer?

Tags: jquery, html, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I need to add objects from Actions to the Reducers Array. For the first time, the value is added to the reducer. When I dispatch the action again, it's overriding the existing value in the array with the object.

check the below code:

Action:

```
let itemImgObj = {
  itemid: "",
  itemimgurl: ""
};
export const setItemsImages = (itemid, itemimgurl) => {
  itemImgObj.itemid = itemid;
  itemImgObj.itemimgurl = itemimgurl;
  console.log("as", itemImgObj);
  return {
    type: 'SET_ITEMS_IMAGES',
    itemImgObj
  };
};
```

Reducer:

```
const Reducer = (state = { cartItemsImages= [] }, action) => {
  console.log(action);
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_ITEMS_IMAGES':
      return {
        ...state,
        cartItemsImages: [...state.cartItemsImages, action.itemImgObj]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

How to update the array value with the object from the action on every dispatch?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you always set the value of `state` to `cartItemsImages` of an empty array. So whenever the reducer is called, the value of your state is always an empty array, that why it overrided the existing value instead of append new one.

You can do the following code:

```
// declare a new const which contains your cartItemsImages
const initialSate = {
   cartItemsImages: []
};

const Reducer = (state = initialSate, action) => {
  console.log(action);
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_ITEMS_IMAGES':
      return {
        ...state,
        cartItemsImages: [...state.cartItemsImages, action.itemImgObj]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```